# AWS amplify - upload files offline in react native expo application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

all,

I am building an offline-first application using **AWS DataStore** with react native expo, but other than the primitive data type, I also have complex data type like files(pdf, images,doc), I want the same offline feature for those documents. The function for offline uploading will be: when it is offline, the user can still do the uploading, the file will be save somewhere(which allow users to access still, like what the DataStore doing now). When the device i back online, the non-uploaded file will be synced/uploaded to S3.

The amplify backedn application I am using is already included the Auth, Api, **Storage** services. But for the Storage service, I can only use it when I am online to upload files to S3, but I want the uploading files have the offline feature as well. This article here mentioned that **AWS mobile SDK for android** is providing the offlie uploading: https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/storage/graphql-api/q/platform/android/#client-code, but there is no where which mentioned something for JavaScript.

If anyone has idea of this, I apprecaite if you can share.

Thank you